# How to pass a value between two different nodejs functions called by 2 different graphql mutations?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to pass the data between two things. I will now explain it in detail. First graphql query calls a function func1() which is like

```
func1(){
  const a = await func2();
  return a;
}

func2(){
  return 7;
}

func3(value){
  return value
}
```

this func2 is returning an integer for example 7. For now I was using console input but now I want to get this result from another graphql mutation which calls a function func3(). I pass the required value for example 7 in the graphql mutation arguments which gets passed to function func3. How can I wait for this func3's value in func1? Please help and if you want me to elaborate any specific thing, I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: Maybe share example of your graphql implementation?

Comment: if you will use await in func2 for func3 then func1 will wait for all queries to handle.
Like:
async func1(){
  const a = await func2();
  return a;
}
async func2(){
  return await func3(1200);
}
async func3(value){
  return value
}

Comment: @ikhvjs i would if I could. Sorry.

Comment: @AsadHaroon this was just an example of func3. The graphql calls this function not func2. The value I get in func3 is via the graphql but you are already passing one when calling func3 in func2

Comment: Because you have mentioned in the code that func3 have value params. Please post more clear requirement so that it will more understandable to me or everyone.